# How to use jQuery toggle function in a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the jQuery toggle function on 20 elements, so I have used for loop.

The following the code only prints the last function, that means 20th toggle function.

I want to call all the toggle function, how do I do it?

```
for(var _rr=1;_rr<=20;_rr++) {
    $("#scell_img"+_rr).toggle(function () {
            $("#scell_img1").attr('src','./resources/img/cancercell/cell_'+_rr+'.png');
            _US620310CD_1._smallclickcount = _US620310CD_1._smallclickcount + 1;
        }, function () {
            $("#scell_img"+_rr).attr('src','./resources/img/cancercell/cell'+_rr+'.png');
            _US620310CD_1._smallclickcount = _US620310CD_1._smallclickcount - 1;
    });
}
```

Comment: It's calling all of them extremely fast, you probably only see the 20th iteration.

Comment: Your use of `.toggle()` was deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9. http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: pls send examples using jsfiddle.

Comment: @tymeJV answer is probably what is going on but here is a more complete explanation. The `for()` loop does not wait for the previous toggle to finish before executing the current loop of instructions. The `for()` loop only takes milliseconds to complete but I bet each toggle takes much longer so jQuery is just restarting the toggle for every iteration.

Comment: Isn't this the classic example of closure closing over variables, not values?

Comment: @möter ya, looks like it!

Comment: someone write it up, I'm too lazy.

Comment: @möter `for(var _rr=1;_rr<=20;_rr++) {
    (function(_rr){
        /*...*/
    }(_rr));
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the variable `_rr` is accessed via a closure in the callback functions so it's value is 20 on every call of the callbacks. Try this:

```
for(var _rr=1; _rr<=20;_rr++) (function(_rr) {
    $("#scell_img"+_rr).toggle(function () {
            $("#scell_img1").attr('src','./resources/img/cancercell/cell_'+_rr+'.png');
            _US620310CD_1._smallclickcount = _US620310CD_1._smallclickcount + 1;
        }, function () {
            $("#scell_img"+_rr).attr('src','./resources/img/cancercell/cell'+_rr+'.png');
            _US620310CD_1._smallclickcount = _US620310CD_1._smallclickcount - 1;
    });
})(_rr);
```

The wrapping function provides a new scope where there is a new variable (also named `_rr`) whose value is not changed by the loop.